# getKeyName in Laravel 10 causes issue in test when slug is primary key

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I have been working on rest api and now I am working on some tests, but since I want to use slug on my model as primary key (usual setup with getKeyName) I have strange behaviour. For example for this create method:

```php
$modelInstance = Model::create([
    'title' => 'Old Title',
    'slug' => Str::slug('Old Title'),
    'description' => 'Old description',
    'rating' => 4.2,
]);
```

I get these results when dump test:

```
#original: array:6 [
  "title" => "Old Title"
  "slug" => 9
  "description" => "Old description"
  "rating" => 4.2
  "updated_at" => "2023-11-17 08:45:08"
  "created_at" => "2023-11-17 08:45:08"
]
#changes: []
#casts: []
#classCastCache: []
#attributeCastCache: []
```

Then when I comment this:

```
public function getKeyName(): string
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

part in my model and run the same test I get this:

```
#original: array:7 [
  "title" => "Old Title"
  "slug" => "old-title"
  "description" => "Old description"
  "rating" => 4.2
  "updated_at" => "2023-11-17 08:47:31"
  "created_at" => "2023-11-17 08:47:31"
  "id" => 9
]
#changes: []
```

I haven't worked much with Laravel 10 lately, but is there something I am missing and I should be aware of?

Comment: you are not considering the `$incrementing` field, it is involved in model creation in the `performInsert()` method

Comment: @DenisSinyukov not sure I have understood what you wanted to say :D So far when I have used this getKeyName it just makes app use slug as primary key but still in the database id would be created independently because it is still `auto incrementing` value but slug would always have provided values. Now I have issue that slug does not take provided data, instead seems like it uses id auto incrementing values there.

Comment: try setting all the values as you want
```php     
class Model {
    public $incrementing = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'slug';
    protected $keyType = 'string';
```

Comment: @DenisSinyukov hm, this seems to be doing its magic but when I create model it does not return me id property. Is this related to this fix or? Also, will this cause any issues to the id column?

Comment: As a result, now the `id` field will not be used when CRUD results. All the focus is on the `slug` field. `incrementing` - says that it is not necessary to plus by itself

`primaryKey` - getKeyName() returns its value and says that this is now the primary field.

`keyType` - used for where queries and so on inside Builder.

Comment: @DenisSinyukov cool, ty. If you want, put this as a comment so I can flag it as the answer.

Comment: Remember to always read the documentation, you have all info there: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#primary-keys

Comment: @matiaslauriti that would not help me much because I have used this 1000 times but now seems like it won't work as it did on the previous versions of Laravel? But thanks anyways ^^

Comment: @devsead clearly you did not do it right, you marked as correct what the documentation link I had shared is saying...

Comment: @matiaslauriti please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting all the values as you want php

```php
class Model {     
  public $incrementing = false;     
  protected $primaryKey = 'slug';     
  protected $keyType = 'string'; 
}
```

As a result, now the id field will not be used when CRUD results. All the focus is on the slug field.

- `incrementing` - says that it is not necessary to plus by itself
- `primaryKey` - *getKeyName()* returns its value and says that this is now the primary field.
- `keyType` - used for where queries and so on inside **Builder**.